# Laravel 10 - belongsTo with select doesn't append attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have following relation:

**User model**

```
 protected $appends = [
        'full_name',
        'avatar',
    ];

    public function company(): HasOne
    
        {
            return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
        }

/**
     * The getter that return accessible URL for user photo.
     *
     * @return Attribute
     */
    public function avatar(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: static function (?string $value, array $attributes) {

                asset(str_replace('public', 'storage', self::$avatarPath)
                    . '_' .
                    $attributes['full_name'] . '_' . $attributes['id'] . '.webp'
                );
            },
        );
    }

public function fullName(): Attribute
    {
        return new Attribute(
            get: fn () => $this->first_name .' ' . $this->last_name
        );
    }
```

**Company model**

```
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And this query:

```
public static function adminTableData(): Builder
    {
        return self::query()->with(['user' => function($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name');
    }])->paginate(10)->toJson();
    }
```

This is the error I am getting:

> ```
> Undefined array key "full_name"
> ```

in the **avatar method**

```
 $attributes['full_name'] . '_' . $attributes['id'] . '.webp'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why the attribute isn't created when I use **with method**?

Answer (score 0):

Because `full_name` is not actually a model attribute, you can use it like an attribute thanks to accessors/mutators.

Use `$this` instead of the `$attributes` array:

```php
/**
 * The getter that return accessible URL for user photo.
 *
 * @return Attribute
 */
public function avatar(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: static function (?string $value, array $attributes) {

            asset(str_replace('public', 'storage', self::$avatarPath)
                . '_' .
                $this->full_name . '_' . $attributes['id'] . '.webp'
            );
        },
    );
}
```